# What does it mean for an object to be wrapped around a database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, architecture

Trying to learn Rails active record and having a hard time understanding what it means for an object to be wrapped around a table. I've already taken a look at some posts that talks about the Active Record pattern but I'm having trouble understanding what it means to "wrap a row".

What does Martin Fowler mean when he [says](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html):

> An object that wraps a row in a database table [...]

Comment: It means that instead of directly manipulating the row in your database table, you manipulate the object that corresponds to the row. Just like a wrapper function wraps its underlying function in a general sense. Also note that it doesn't say _"wrap an object"_ but _"wraps a row"_ – not the object is wrapped, but the row (by the object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one context it also means that you map all the columns of that row in properties or data on the object. Hence any interactions that happens in terms of changing the data in that row happens via the object and it's properties.